# SQL query to get last record of every minute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which is updated every second with some values. I want to retrieve the last record of every minute.

I have tried this code, but it is returning all the records.

```
SELECT 
    t0.brandID, t0.brandName, t0.cdt, t0.udt, t0.brandstatus  
FROM 
    brands t0 
WHERE  
    t0.cdt BETWEEN '2013-11-15' and '2014-11-15' 
GROUP BY 
    t0.brandID, t0.brandName, t0.cdt, t0.udt, t0.brandstatus,(datepart(minute, t0.cdt) / 1)
```

My table structure is:

```
ID  brandname     cdt                          udt  brandstatus addedby
1   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.120 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1
2   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.121 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1
3   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.122 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1          
4   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.123 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1
5   khasim  2013-11-02 19:17:57.700 2013-11-15 19:17:57.700 1   2
6   tanveer 2013-11-03 19:18:05.947 2013-11-15 19:18:05.947 1   2
7   abcdef  2013-11-04 20:50:06.783 2013-11-15 20:50:06.787 1   4
```

Expected result is:

```
 ID  brandname     cdt                          udt  brandstatus addedby

    4   khasim  2013-11-01 19:14:18.123 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123 1   1
    5   khasim  2013-11-02 19:17:57.700 2013-11-15 19:17:57.700 1   2
    6   tanveer 2013-11-03 19:18:05.947 2013-11-15 19:18:05.947 1   2
    7   abcdef  2013-11-04 20:50:06.783 2013-11-15 20:50:06.787 1   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to add numbering coupled with `PARTITION BY`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY brandname, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, cdt), 0)
                ORDER BY cdt DESC
             )
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Id
```

This:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, cdt), 0)
```

*rounds down* the `cdt` to its nearest minute, i.e. `2013-11-01 19:14:18.123` to `2013-11-01 19:14:00.000`.

Comment: `DATEPART(MINUTE,cdt)` will also get the minute part

Comment: Yeah, sure the minute part. But that will mess up the partition. I guess I have worded it poorly.

Comment: your solution is what i was looking for, but what do you mean by mess up the partition i have changed partition by to cdt(datetime) and checked there isn't any problem. where i should specify the "between" date

Comment: I'm talking about if you partition by `DATEPART(MINUTE, cdt)` alone.

Comment: how to modify the above query for every 5 minute interval or " n" minute interval

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby
FROM (
  SELECT ID, brandname, cdt, udt, brandstatus, addedby,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY brandname, 
                                         CAST(udt AS DATE),
                                         CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), udt, 114) 
                            ORDER BY udt DESC) AS rn
  FROM brands) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

This part:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), udt, 114)
```

is used in order to extract hour and minute from `udt` field.

Comment: can you please explain this in brief as i have to do the same for every hour, every day, every minute  between two dates and you are doing partition by brandname can we do it by cdt(datetime)

Comment: @Tan `ROW_NUMBER` is applied over partitions (slices) of records having the **same** (1) `brandname`, (2) `date` from `udt` **and** (3) hour, minute from `udt`. For every such partition the latest record is being picked. You can apply the same function on `cdt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
    SELECT t0.brandID, t0.brandName, t0.cdt, t0.udt, t0.brandstatus FROM brands t0 WHERE t0.cdt BETWEEN '2013-11-15' and '2014-11-15' 
  and t0.cdt in (select MAX(cdt) from brands group by (CONVERT(CHAR(16),cdt,120)));
```