# How to query max and min records of every second within a period of time in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres 9.6 table with hundreds of millions of records in 'prices' table with only four columns: uid, price, unit, dt. dt is a datetime in standard format like '2017-05-01 00:00:00.585' with fractions of a second. It might be none to dozens record each second.

I need to find MAX and MIN price record in some time period. I can quite easily to select a period using

```
SELECT uid, price, unit from prices
WHERE dt > '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND dt < '2017-05-01 02:59:59.999'
```

Thanks to [krokodilko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/krokodilko) I can [find first and last records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256906/how-to-query-just-the-last-record-of-every-second-within-a-period-of-time-in-pos) of each second, but can't adapt it to MIN and MAX.

Could some please help me with finding MIX and MAX price values in records per each second in given period of time?

Comment: Do you need results for every second which has data, or for every second in the interval, whether it has data or not?

Comment: if there is no data, I'd rather have NULL. Such approach will make further processing easier. however if it is not possible, having datetime for min and max where data presented I can fill in gaps grammaticality.

Comment: Tell once again, dt is SQL datetime (for me this is 'standard'), or string in format like above?

Comment: for pure datetime column, read about SELECT ... EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ..., group on this result etc

Comment: dt s timestamp type. Although, you are right indeed, it works SELECT date_trunc('second', dt) as time, min(price), max(price)
FROM prices
WHERE dt >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00' AND dt < '2017-05-01 00:00:59'
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time;